# cron job not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cronjob, crontab

It is little weird now that cron job is not working as i have set. I have set weekly job to send email but i am receiving multiple emails daily. Below is my code;

```
# sends email every monday at 4:00 am 
00 04 * * 1  /usr/bin/ruby /home/mbm/www/current/script/runner /home/mbm/www/current/app/models/add_to_delayed_job.rb -e production
```

- 00 -> Minutes
- 04 -> Hours (0-24)
- 1 -> Days / 0-6 / Sun - Sat

Sending email is fine but the time is not working so far as set.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which crontab file is this set in?

Comment: At what times are the multiple e-mails you are getting being sent?  This is probably a good clue into how this is being misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check out the [Whenever gem](http://github.com/javan/whenever), a nice ruby gem to automate the creation of cronjobs. [Screencast about it here (Railscasts)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby).

Then you would do something like this:

```
every :monday do
  rake "email:send" # My configuration
end
```

Adds `0 0 * * 1 cd /my/path && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env rake email:send` to my crontab file

But as answer, try as Raghuram said, use `0 4 * * 1` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the post but I think what I am doing is much less than what it takes with gem. I will look around what is the problem with my code. If not then I have will try with whenever.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your cronjob is set up correctly.  Does all email stop if you comment it out?  (i.e. could there be another job set up somewhere else?)